# Calling a member function with member data by using for_each

Tags: c++, foreach, reference, pass-by-reference

Dear all, I would like to call a member function (that expects a reference) for each object  of (let's say) a vector that is a member of the same class, as the following code shows:

```
#include <functional>  
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Stuff {
  double x;
};

class Test {
public:
  void f1(Stuff & thing);
  void f2(void);
  vector<Stuff> things;
};

void Test::f1(Stuff & thing) {
  ; // do nothing
}

void Test::f2(void) {
  for_each(things.begin(), things.end(), f1);
}

int main(void)
{

  return 0;
}
```

This codes gives me a compiler error related to *unresolved overloaded function type* . I have tried also with bind, but it seems that the references requisite in f1 is one problem. I know I am missing something important here, so I take this opportunity to solve my problem and to learn. At the moment, I can't install boost, but I would like to know also if boost is useful to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The function you want to call cannot be simply identified by `f1` but should be referred to as `&Test::f1` (as in : member function `f1` of class `Test`)
- Function `f1` does not take a single argument : as any non-static member function it has an implicit `this` parameter of type `Test * const`
- Finally, a standard bind won't be able to do the trick because it doesn't handle  parameters passed by reference.

[Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html) would indeed be a great option :

```
std::for_each(things.begin(), things.end(), boost::bind(&Test::f1, this, _1));
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can also use C++11's `std::bind` (which is identical to Boost.Bind): `std::for_each(things.begin(), things.end(), std::bind(&Test::f1, this, std::placeholders::_1));`